All processes freeze
Hey guys so I upgraded to 24.04 just now and it has been running relatively smoothly till now. However every time I try to start any "process" with sudo apt upgrade, sudo apt install or sudo apt autoremove, it will always end up getting stuck with a progress bar and saying it's "unpacking switch-bsp (5.1.2-25+24.04) over (5.1.2-24+24.04)". It like that saying "all ways lead to Rome". It's also impossible to use ssh to execute larger commands, which is shitty. I'm pretty new so please be patient with me. Appreciate all help.

Please provide detail; e.g. copy the command you use and the output text from the terminal into your question and mark it as "code".
